# how close the first recordset to get another value form cbox

Tags: vba, recordset

I have this code, i get some values from a list, is okey, and I want to get another value from cbox, I've tried to close the recordset but, I have an error:

```
 Private Sub cmdAñadir_Click()
 Dim VARITEM
 Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
 Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT TipoProducto, Descripcion, Proveedor, RefSap, RefProveedor FROM tblCarrito")

 For Each VARITEM In Me.Lista0.ItemsSelected
     RS.AddNew 
         RS!TipoProducto = Me.Lista0.Column(1, VARITEM)
         RS!Descripcion = Me.Lista0.Column(2, VARITEM)
         RS!Proveedor = Me.Lista0.Column(3, VARITEM)
         RS!RefSap = Me.Lista0.Column(4, VARITEM)
         RS!RefProveedor = Me.Lista0.Column(7, VARITEM)
     RS.Update
     RS.Close    
Next


Dim rst As Recordset
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblCarrito")
 With rst
      .AddNew
      .Fields("destino") = Cuadro_combinado70.Value
      .Update
 End With

 End Sub
```

Comment: You do not close any record set. Try `RS.Close`

Comment: What is the error and which line cause the error?

Comment: yes, I try it. I've error 3314 runtime. Write a value In field tblCarrito.TipoProducto and the program stops in .Update at the end

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved, I use the bucle for each to catch the values of cbox and the values of list.
thank you for your attention